# Cannot connect React website with Firestore

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, compiler-errors

I tried to connect my website with Firestore but it did not work.

Here's my **config.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

const firebaseConfig = {
      //cred
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebase;
```

And this is **Signup.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import  firebase  from "./config";

class Signup extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '-',
            email: '-',
        };
    }

    render(){
        return (
            //do something
    )}
}
```

it always gives an error:

> ./src/config.js
>
> > Attempted import error: 'firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'firebase').

When I change **config.js**

`import firebase from 'firebase/app'`

to

`import firebase from 'firebase'`

it gives this error:

> ./src/config.js
>
> > Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'C:\Users\NITRO\register\src'

If I change **Config.js** (again)

`import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'`

This is an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initializeApp')

I can't figure it out what is wrong with it.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the default export with a named export like this :

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

For more information, take a look here : [https://firebase.google.com](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)